# What should I do to point my domain name to a windows 2008 dedicated server?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have read this topic
[What's involved getting domain name pointed at my dedicated server (Win2008)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/67888/whats-involved-getting-domain-name-pointed-at-my-dedicated-server-win2008)

but it's not precise enough for me.

At my registrar I have

```
A Records  
Name (ex. www)
TTL (ex. 3600)
IPv4 Address (ex. 192.168.1.1)
```

When I tried to add www and the IP address of my own server it says error processing the request, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using your WAN address - so that will not work. `192.168.x.x` addresses are not routable on the internet and therefor will not be accepted. [IPChicken.com](http://www.ipchicken.com) is a great place to find you external IP.

Comment: I'm not using this IP, it's the example IP from my provider :)

Answer (score 0):

On your server, go to http://www.wimip.com/ in a web browser. That IP address there? That's what you need to put into your DNS. As Grishanko said, `192.168.x.x` addresses are not valid for use on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

To find out your WAN IP address you can use a web site like [What Is My IP Address](http://www.whatismyip.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it didn't work but the registrar did it finally.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.